# Clear both is getting rid of centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

All I want to do is simply center my divs, the most common thing in webdesign. But for some reason it is turning out to be the most grueling endeavor that I have ever partook in. My inline style is such ...

```
<div class="span10" id="about-div" style="margin: 0 auto; clear:both;">
  content
</div>

<div class="span10" id="other-div" style="margin: 0 auto; clear:both;">
  content
</div>
```

Thats it. It should work, but somehow clear:both with ruin the centering. clear:both is required since my div's will automatically appear on the same line if this is omitted. How do I fix this? Btw span10 is a bootstrap class mean my divs are about 720px wide.

Comment: Why are you clearing ?

Comment: What's the CSS for `.span10`? And `#about-div` and `#other-div`?

Comment: if `clear:both` is having any effect at all, then you have some floated elements around (`clear` is intended to clear the floats). You haven't told us anything about what elements are floated, but there's a strong probability that it's the floats that are messing up your layout -- floats and centering are not easy to get working together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for divs to appear alongside each other (and based on my knowledge of Twitter bootsrap) your divs are most likely being floated. If this is the case then centering will become extremely awkward. Floats and centering do not mix. Your best bet (considering you seem to want to put both divs back to being non-floated) is to do the following:

```
<div class="span10" id="about-div" style="margin: 0 auto; float:none;">
  content
</div>

<div class="span10" id="other-div" style="margin: 0 auto; float:none;">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: Right on, this was the only viable fix.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but you could try

```
position:absolute; left:50%; margin-left:-360px;}
```

Comment: I was hoping instead of doing that, the browser could just center it normally.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `</br>` at the end of each line?  That will cause the break without messing with floats.